# Pseudo color plot of random lattice in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, data-visualization

I have a list that I use to represent a lattice:

```
lattice = [[np.array([0., 0.]), 1.5], [np.array([5., 0.]), 2], [np.array([10., 0.]), 0.7]]
```

For each component in the list, the first array represents its location, and the second number represents a certain rotational degree of the component. For example, this lattice I listed above have three components: one located at (0, 0) rotated 1.5 pi; one located at (5, 0) rotated 2 pi; one located at (10, 0) rotated 0.7 pi.

To illustrate it better, the lattices I am looking at are 2D. In the graphs below, each arrow shows one component, I set the system up such that the components don't overlap with each other (thank you Johan for the notes!)

[lattice visualization 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Bxt.png)
[lattice visualization 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4jjC.png)

I want to generate a pseudo color plot that will allow me to visualize the rotation of each component with color at its specific location.

> For example, at each location I:
>
> 1. generate a circle,
> 2. color the circle based on the rotation angle (second value in the array) using a color bar(color darker as the value increase).

Is there any possible way to do this in python?

Thank you so much for reading this post and I hope you have a great day no matter you reply or not! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about square lattices of 1x1 cell size?  What do you do with overlapping positions?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want a system in which you will pass the coordinates and rotated angles, then draw a circle at a specific location with color. You can achieve through [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) in python, in which you start the turtle at a specific position and then move the turtle according to your angle, and draw the circle and set the color that you want.